# Assuming *only* that $\sin^2{\theta}$ + $\cos^2{\theta} = 1$, show that $\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}\le1/2$

Tags: trigonometry

> Assuming *only* that $\sin^2{\theta}$ + $\cos^2{\theta} = 1$, show that $\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}\le1/2$.

I only know how to do it using calculus!

Comment: Does $a^2+b^2 \geqslant 2ab$ count as calculus?

Comment: @DanielFischer certainly not. $(a - b)^2 \ge 0$ and so $a^2 + b^2 \ge 2ab$.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$0 \leqslant (\sin\theta - \cos\theta)^2 = \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta - 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = 1 - 2\sin\theta\cos\theta.$$

From that we deduce $2\sin\theta\cos\theta \leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The AM-GM Inequality with 2 variables states that $\dfrac{a + b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$, or perhaps more suitable for this question would be the form $\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{2} \geq ab$.

$\dfrac{sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \geq \sqrt{sin^2\theta cos^2\theta} = sin\theta cos\theta$

$\therefore sin\theta cos\theta \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$